# Angular API authentication by sessions

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I have a API server that have a POST method to login user and it stores the logged in status in session. Then after success login I have available method to get the current user information. It works well in Postman but in Angular application the second method returns that I'm not logged in. I tried with $http withCredentials flag and with angular service $cookieStore but it's still not working.

I don't know exactly how to deal with it. I don't know what should be set or stored to properly handle APIs session.  Can you give me some examples?

Comment: please include relevant code.

Comment: If your server does the authentication in cookie based then angular has nothing to do with it. Once you create a valid authenticated session with server usually everything is managed with http only cookies. Also you can't get hold of http only cookies with JS for security reasons.

Comment: @fernando thank you for answer. Now, when I change in API that user saves in cookie, angular app works well. In this case it's correct answer.